# Error while trying to implement Facebook connect with Javascript SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Getting following error when trying to implement Facebook connect with Facebook JavaScript SDK:-

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://staticxx.facebook.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at ga (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:48:2439)
>       at Object.ba [as send] (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:48:2533)
>       at Object.aa [as whenReady] (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:50:2987)
>       at Object.x [as init] (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:48:3091)
>       at Object.w [as create] (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:48:963)
>       at https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:50:2447
>       at a (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:50:3023)
>       at require (https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:31:585)
>       at https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/fTmIQU3LxvB.js?version=42:50:3146

I am using the following Code:-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

   FB.init({ appId: fbAppId, 
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    function updateButton(response) {
        button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user is already logged in and connected
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info, calFrom,fbAppId);
            });
        } else {
            //user is not connected to your app or logged out
            button.onclick = function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                            login(response, info, calFrom,fbAppId);
                        });
                    } else {
                        //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                    }
                }, { scope: 'publish_actions,manage_pages' });
            }
        }
    }

    // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
    FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);     
} ());
```